# vim iab calls function to insert different time(stamp)

Tags: ruby, vim, time, scripting, abbreviation

i want the following in a vim buffer, best independent of the Operation System.

1. typing `today` will be replaced by `=20130716`. *The equal sign is wanted!*
2. typing `tomorrow` will be replaced by `=20130717`
3. typing `nextweek` will be replaced by `=20130723`

*as Infomation for the above lines: today is 16. July 2013*

For 1. I can use (which does not work on Windows):

```
iab <expr> tod strftime("=%Y%m%d")
```

For 2. and 3. I can use (No Windows and add an extra and *unwanted* Carriage Return):

```
iab tom <C-o>:r !date -v+1d "+\%Y\%m\%d"<CR>
```

For 2. and 3. I can use (OS independent but as well extra and *unwanted* carriage return):

```
 iab too <ESC>:r !ruby -e "puts (Time.now + 24*60*60).strftime('\%Y\%m\%d')"<CR>
```

How can I accomplish my wants. Best OS independent and the ruby way :) For a first approach It would be nice for 2. and 3. to avoid the *unwanted* carriage return.

My vim has ruby build in, so perhaps there is a smarter way to invoke the ruby commands shown by me. Currently I do not know a better way.

Answer (score 3):

Try with following mappings in Insert Mode:

```
:inoremap <expr> today strftime( "=%Y%m%d", localtime() )
:inoremap <expr> tomorrow strftime( "=%Y%m%d", localtime() + (24 * 3600) )
:inoremap <expr> nextweek strftime( "=%Y%m%d", localtime() + (7 * 24 * 3600) )
```